# Delete with JPA and ManyToMany

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I followed this [tutorial](https://hellokoding.com/registration-and-login-example-with-spring-security-spring-boot-spring-data-jpa-hsql-jsp/) to setup a spring boot project with a login/registration system with jpa and spring security. In the tutorial code it produces a 'users', 'roles' and 'users_roles' table. Now I wanted to add a route to the controller that would delete a user by id by adding this route to the controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/user_delete", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String deleteUser(@RequestParam long id) {
        userService.deleteUser(id);
        return "redirect:/admin/users";
    }
```

and added a delete method to UserService like so:

```
    @Override
    public void deleteUser(long id) {
        User u = userRepository.findById(id).get();
        Set<Role> roles = u.getRoles();
        while(roles.iterator().hasNext()) 
        {   
            Role role = roles.iterator().next();
            Set<User> users = role.getUsers();
            users.remove(u);
            role.setUsers(users);
            roleRepository.save(role);
            roles.remove(role);
        }
        u.setRoles(roles);
        userRepository.save(u);
        userRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
```

I also added a simple error controller like this:

```
@Controller("error")
public class ErrorController {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ModelAndView handleException(HttpServletRequest request, Exception ex) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();

        mv.addObject("exception", ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        mv.addObject("url", request.getRequestURL());

        mv.setViewName("error");
        return mv;
    }

}
```

Now whenever I call the delete route it goes to my error page with no real message in the console. I tried adding `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` or REMOVE but neither work, only when starting the app now I get this exception message (app still starts):

```
Error executing DDL "alter table users_roles add constraint FK2o0jvgh89lemvvo17cbqvdxaa foreign key (user_id) references users (id)" via JDBC Statement
```

How can I adapt the code from the tutorial to delete a User?

Comment: Set the cascade to `REMOVE` and remove the usages from the object (on the other side) before removing the element. Does this work?

Comment: So set cascade to remove on user and remove the `Set<User> users` in role? or do you mean clear the Set<Role> roles before deleting? I have tried clearing the set that didn't work

Comment: Is the relation bidirectional?

Comment: its bidirectional

Comment: Do `user.getRoles().remove(user);` or similar (and maybe saving the other object) before deleting the object from the database.

Comment: I tried removing the Set<User> from the Role class to make it not bidirectional and I clear the Set<Role> and save before deleting but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Remove the user from the role, save the role and delete the user. Does this work?

Comment: i tried this (I updated the delete method shown in the question to reflect this) but still doesn't work

Comment: Can you add your entities here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you have an entity with a `bidirectional` relationship as shown below.

You need add `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` and `orphanRemoval = true`, you can also try `cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE`

```
@Entity
public class User implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long userId;// primary key

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Role> roles;
}

@Entity
public class Role implements java.io.Serializable {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! I was missing the fetch part